# Link to a file external of the application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-7, web, web-config

I have a website with 3 applications. In the website root there are 3 folders (each one contains one asp.net application) and a file named `index.html` with 3 links like that:

```
<a href="Linea1/Pages/Sintesi.aspx"> Linea 1 </a> <br />
<a href="Linea2/Pages/Sintesi.aspx"> Linea 2 </a> <br />
<a href="Linea3/Pages/Sintesi.aspx"> Linea 3 </a> <br />
```

In the webconfig of each application there are an appSettings value like that:

```
<add key="linkPaginaHome" value="Index.html" />
```

In each page of the three apps there is a link and his href value is readed from the web.config. 
In other words, I want allow you to go to the `index.html` page from each one of the applications of the site and this parameter must be configurable.

What should I write in the webconfig value to make it points to the `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used the full url:

```
http://localhost:2012/Index.html
```

instead of writing only

```
Index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Link : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument